SGD Code from GitHub Repo Fails to Run: Error in Derived Results
Microsoft Intrinsic Private SGD GitHub, i read the file readme but it still error when run derived_result.
python wrapper.py sweep --cfg mnist_binary --num_seeds 25 --num_replaces 30

this run but
python wrapper.py derive --cfg mnist_binary --t 2000 

not i think the code error and can not run
i have try to change some code in the file such as file derived:
bad_rows_vali = vali['ce'].astype('str').str.contains('\[')

i have to change ce to binary_cross_entropy
